# How to add a due date/ expiry date text? (visual studio)

Tags: visual-studio, date

I was wondering how to show a date for 5 days after the button is clicked. Here is my code so far;

```
decTotalAfterDiscount = (decTotal) - ((decTotal) * .10m);

        txtTotal.Text = decTotal.ToString("C");
        txtTotal_discounted.Text = decTotalAfterDiscount.ToString("C");
        txtExpiry.Text = DataSetDateTime.Local.ToString("C");
```

Comment: What is `DataSetDateTime`?

Comment: Also, please stop using Systems Hungarian Notation: The `dec` prefix in `decTotalAfterDiscount` and `decTotal`. is entirely redundant.

Comment: The discount expression can be simplified to `Decimal totalAfterDiscount = total * 0.9;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `.ToString("C")` is to format a number as a currency amount, but dates aren't currencies.

  - Use `"d"` to format a `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` value as a short-date using the current user's culture settings. **Avoid hard-coding specific date formats**.
- Use `DateTime.Now` to get the current user's *local computer time* (but only in desktop applications - it does not work for server-side web applications). Use `DateTime.UtcNow` for the current UTC time. I assume using Local Computer Time is appropriate in this case.
- Is `txtExpiry` a `TextBox`? If so, is it meant to be user-editable? Why not use a `DatePicker` or a read-only `Label`?

To answer your question directly, do this:

```
txtExpiry.Text = DateTime.Now.AddDays( 5 ).ToString( "d" );
```